# RadioButton.setTypeFace not working

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to set the font for a RadioButton which is created in runtime. But the setTypeFace is not working, nothing happens

```
        for (int i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
            RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(V.getContext());
            radioButtonView.setText(schools[i]);
            radioButtonView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            radioButtonView.setTextSize(25);
            radioButtonView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
            radioButtonView.setOnClickListener(mThisButtonListener);
            radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
            //radioButtonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            //radioButtonView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            radioButtonView.setId(i);
            //((ViewGroup)layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your font file in assets folder and set font with below code..

```
Typeface rbfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "shruti_1.ttf");
radioButtonView.setTypeface(rbfont);
```

Comment: i am using the default fonts of android, do i still new doing this way ??